# Cambiar propiedad css dependiendo del navegador utilizado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

El siguiente código debería aumentar el espacio entre las letras cuando se abre en safari pero parece ignorar la orden que cambia la propiedad css pese a que sí que sale la alerta.
Gracias.

```js
function BrowserDetection() {

    //Check if browser is IE or not
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is InternetExplorer");
    }
    //Check if browser is Chrome or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is Chrome");
    }
    //Check if browser is Firefox or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is FireFox");
    }
    //Check if browser is Safari or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
  alert("Browser is Opera");
        $('#slogan').css('letter-spacing', '3px');
    }
    //Check if browser is Opera or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is Opera");
    }
}
BrowserDetection();
```

```css
#slogan{
color:red; 
font-family: MonkGothic;
font-size:30px;
letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="slogan">
AA
AA
AA
AA
</pre>
```

Comment: ¿No será que falta poner `body` entre comillas (simples o dobles), es decir, `$('body').css('letter-spacing', '3px');`?

Comment: No @PaulVargas de hecho es un error que me he dejado mientras hacía pruebas para ver si era problema de la etiqueta ya que sólo quiero que afecte a #slogan

Comment: Esta pregunta se parece mucho a [la pregunta que realizaste antes](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7677/bloquear-una-propiedad-css-para-determinados-navegadores-y-anchos-de-pantalla), parece que lo que se quiere obtener es lo mismo (aplicar un CSS sólo para cierto navegador/resolución), ¿no?

Comment: Sí @AlvaroMontoro apago la otra :)

Comment: No es que la apagues, pero desde el punto de vista de SO, creo que lo adecuado habría sido añadir esta información a la otra pregunta (alguien con más experiencia que yo podrá decirte)

Comment: Detectar el user agent para aplicar estilo es una [mala idea](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/). Aqui tienes una [guía](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way) de las estrategias que debes emplear para lidiar con tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un bug, Safari no funciona correctamente la propiedad `letter-spacing`:

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/161521

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20606

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117742

de hecho existe una pregunta en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811225/is-there-a-way-to-make-css-letter-spacing-0-5-px

Comment: @IvanSoler si el bug fue resuelto en 2014-01-08 aprox, puede mirar con la ultima version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Release_history de funcionarle podria mirar si alguna/s de las versiones anteriores se les aplico algun parche o similar.

Comment: @AngelAngel Es lo que comenta en el thread, que fue resuelto, pero teniendo una última versión y ahora actualizando a Version 9.1 (10601.5.17.4) en Safari, tampoco funciona.